# Python 'grid()' ignores row/column/sticky options

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a lil' card game. It's one player, against a CPU, and it's just as simple as that. A game. However, games aren't fun if they aren't played by the rules, and in this case, the `.grid()` doesn't want to play by it's rules (`.grid(row, column, sticky`). The code executes fine, console reports no error, and it compiles, executes, and "works" completely. However, the image label doesn't move at all.

**NOTE:** I'm not sure if it's because of the method that I use to display images, if it doesn't work with images, or it's just plain bugged.

Here's the code, as well as the output.

## Python

```
crdImg = []
usrStk = None
cpuStk = None
i = 1

#define cards

while i < 57:
  i = i + 1
  crdImg.append('img/cards/%s.png' % (i - 1))

usrStk = crdImg[54]
cpuStk = crdImg[55]

#define card images

usrCrdImg = Image.open(usrStk)
usrCrdBg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(usrCrdImg)
usrCrd = tkinter.Label(self, text="", image=usrCrdBg, borderwidth=1)
usrCrd.grid(row=4, column=4)
usrCrd.image = usrCrdBg
usrCrd.pack()
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: It seems like you are first using `grid`, and then overriding that with `pack`. try to remove `usrCrd.pack()`. Also, I think you should do `CardGame(root).grid()`

Comment: You should add a tkinter tag for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are first positioning the label with `grid`, but then overriding that position with `pack`. Do not use `grid` and `pack` layout managers together!

Remove the line `usrCrd.pack()` and change `CardGame(root).pack()` to `CardGame(root).grid()`, then it should work.

Note, however, that unless you put something into the other rows and columns, `usrCrd.grid(row=4, column=4)` will still put the card in the top-left corner, as the other rows and columns have zero width and height.